# Rcpp: how to get the number of row/ column for a nullable matrix in rcpp

Tags: rcpp, nullable

I found that we could not use `.ncol()` and `.nrow()` to a matrix with type `Nullable<NumericMatrix>` in a function. A simple example is :

```
cppFunction('int getdim(Nullable<NumericMatrix> X_mat) {
  if(X_mat.isNotNull()){
    int col_num = X_mat.ncol();
    return col_num;
  }else{
    return 0;
  }
  }')
```

Is there a way to get the corresponding information conveniently? Thanks!!!

Comment: I already gave you a pointer in the question I closed of yours I closed three hours ago:  when a matrix is not null, you _instantiate it_ and can the query the dims of that instance.  This is STILL a duplicate.  Please study the old questions and existing examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the existing examples show, you *must* instantiante an object when your are in the 'not `NULL`' case:

```
R> Rcpp::cppFunction('int getdim(Nullable<NumericMatrix> X_mat) {
+   if(X_mat.isNotNull()) {
+     NumericMatrix M(X_mat);
+     int col_num = M.ncol();
+     return col_num;
+   }else{
+     return 0;
+   }
+ }')
R> getdim(NULL)
[1] 0
R> getdim(matrix(1:4,2))
[1] 2
R>
```